# Stuck at lock screen

Tags: lock-screen

I was working on a text file a minute ago. I locked my screen to make coffee and I come back and my lock screen is unresponsive. I can move the mouse, but I can't click anywhere and my keyboard doesn't do anything.

I can SSH into the computer and everything seems to be fine.

So:

1. Can I kill the process that is the lock screen? This seems like a security hole, but I suppose maybe not really if I can already ssh and do everything else.

Or :

2. Can I find the temp file for a textedit document and save that real quick, then just reboot the computer?

Comment: Let's try this: press ctrl+alt+f2 and insert the command `killall gnome-screensaver`.

Comment: And then ctrl+alt+f1, or ctrl+alt+f7, I'm on debian now so I'm not sure wich is in ubuntu.

Comment: No luck. I get `gnome-screensaver: no process found`. And I can't find anything related to screensaver when running `top` and `htop` Maybe a graphics bug then? I have two monitors, so nomally when I unplug one the the system will move the screen info to one not the other. But that's not happening at all.

Comment: Marking as answered but I;ll leave the post up for future people to find if the need it.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up. At this point the text document was small enough I can just recreate it with less time then this bug.